# Get attribute value from c#/xpath

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xpath

I have an app.config file, and need to get value of an attribute:

```
<param name="File" value="C:\"/>
```

Liquid XML Studio gives the following xml:

```
/configuration/log4net/appender/param[1]
```

However, what C# code can use xpath to get a value?

Answer (score 26):

Use this XPath:

```
/configuration/log4net/appender/param[@name='File']/@value
```

Depending on how you read the XML, the code for using the XPath may differ a bit. If you're using `XDocument`, you can use the `XPathEvaluate` extension method like so:

```
var eval = xml.XPathEvaluate("/configuration/log4net/appender/param[@name='File']/@value");
var value = ((IEnumerable)eval).OfType<XAttribute>().Single().Value;
```

If you're using `XmlDocument`, there is a `SelectSingleNode()` method. And if you use an `XPathDocument`, you need to compile a `XPathExpression` and then use this XPath against a navigator.

Comment: I get an exception when I try to use XPathSelectElement to try and get an attribute although this may have changed since 2011 when this was answered.  I believe you now have to call XPathEvaluate() like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360398/exception-the-xpath-expression-evaluated-to-unexpected-type-system-xml-linq-xat

Comment: @Benj Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated the answer to be correct.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). See [`XmlNode.SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx) and others.

Example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"<configuration>
<log4net>
<appender>
<param name=""File"" value=""C:\""/>
</appender>
</log4net>
</configuration>");

var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//param[@name = 'File']/@value");

Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

It like ....

```
        var result = XDocument.Load("test.xml").Descendants("param");

        foreach (var p in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Attribute("name"));
        }

        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlDocument and a method SelectSingleNode - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx
It will find a node matching your XPath.

I would do this with LINQ to XML (not with XPath)