# Updating app.config via xpath

Tags: c#

Earlier I raised this question:
[Get attribute value from c#/xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704585/get-attribute-value-from-c-xpath)

And the suggestions worked. However, I now need to update the actula document with a new value. I've tried to set the value property but this does not update the xml document (app.config in this case). What would be the way to update an app.config?

Thanks

Comment: What type of changes are you trying to make inside of the app.config?

Comment: Please write this as an independent question.

Comment: Update the value of an attribute. @Henk, this is independent?

Comment: I think what @Henk is suggesting is for you to explain what you did in the other question to solve it so people don't need to follow a link to get the full story.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to open it with [`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265.aspx)

From there you probably should use the methods of the [configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) object to change the settings, followed by a [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.save.aspx) to save it to disk. But, if you really want to use the XPath methods, you could check the FilePath property and swap to munging it with xml tools.