# How to get the xml tag value from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an xml name as **recipe.xml**

```
<sections>
<section name="Template">
<item key="SkipTemplates" value="C:/Temp/skip.xm;" />
<item key="validateTemplate" value="C:/Temp/validate.xml" />
<item key="PassTemplate" value="C:/Temp/pass.xml" />
</section>
<section name="Version">
<item key="MenuTemplate" value="C:/TempVersion/menu.xml" />
<item key="PassTemplate" value="C:/TempVersion/pass.xml" />
<item key="SkipTemplate" value="C:/TempVersion/skip.xml" />
</section>
</sections>
```

I wish to used C# code to return me the value of each node. For example:
I want to get the value(C:/Temp/validate.xml) for the node that name (validateTemplate)

I have try below code but return me error:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("C:/Mani/recipe.xml");
XmlElement directoryElement = xml.GetElementById("validateTemplate");
string backupPath = directoryElement.GetAttribute("value");
MessageBox.Show(backupPath.ToString());
```

[image]

Comment: For GetElementById to work, it has to be known which attribute is working as ID. This can be done either by a DTD or an XSD. See the Remarks section here: [XmlDocument.GetElementById](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid)

Comment: You can also use the attribute value and get the node with either [LINQ2XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/find-element-specific-attribute) or [XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704585/get-attribute-value-from-c-xpath). Either way, you should include fortification against NullReferenceException in case no element has been found that satisfies your search term.

Comment: @KlausGütter hi, may I get more info from you, i have no ideas by the DTD and XSD  where can be set.

Comment: `validateTemplate` is not the name of node. It's an attribute.

Comment: XPath example: `var node = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//item[@key = 'validateTemplate']/@value"); MessageBox.Show(node?.Value ?? "Not found"); `

Comment: FYI for this exception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it might be easiest to use an [XPath expression](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) to find the item you are looking for. You can turn this into a function that uses the name of the section and item name as parameters.

Something like this:

```cs
var templatePath = xml.DocumentElement?.SelectSingleNode("/sections/section[@name='Template']/item[@key='validateTemplate']/@value")?.Value;
```

or play with it an select all section.items:

```cs
foreach (XmlNode item in xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/sections/section/item"))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.ParentNode.Attributes["name"]?.Value}.{item.Attributes["key"]?.Value}\t{item.Attributes["value"]?.Value}");
}
```